# ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism not doing anything

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Using the code on the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) about ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism, I tried the following...

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions {
  MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
};
Parallel.ForEach(files, (currentFile) => {
  String filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFile);
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(currentFile);
  bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
  bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(newDir, filename));
  Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", filename, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
});
```

However, looking at the thread IDs being output, I can see that it doesn't make any difference at all if I set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism or not. Looking at my CPU monitor, I can see all cores in action, even if I set MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 2.

Am I missing the point here? I thought the idea was to limit the number of threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are passing `po` into `Parallel.ForEach`, so it just uses the default. Use [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Parallel.ForEach` that allows you to pass the `ParallelOptions` into, perhaps this one:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, po, (currentFile) => {
```

Comment: As Jen's came in 2 mins before yours, I will mark that as the answer, but thanks anyway, as yours was equally clear. Please see my comment there as to why I missed this rather obvious point!

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel It's actually the opposite, vcsjones beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @Jens, oops, you're right. In that case, I'll mark this as the answer instead. Thanks to both of you anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the ParallelOptions you define in your loop. You have to use a different overload:

```
Parallel.ForEach<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, ParallelOptions, Action<TSource>)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747(v=vs.110).aspx

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions {
  MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
};
Parallel.ForEach(files, po, (currentFile) => {
  String filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFile);
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(currentFile);
  bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
  bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(newDir, filename));
  Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", filename, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
});
```

Comment: I did wonder about that, but the only examples I saw of MaxDegreeOfParallelism didn't show how to use it in the loop, so I stupidly assumed that maybe it was setting some static property. Did seem odd, as I was creating an instance of ParallelOptions! Thanks